# How to control the property name of a serialised object using Apex

Tags: apex, json, xml, serialization

**BACKGROUND**

I need to generate the below JSON data:

**JSON**

```
{
  "Type": "ACCPAYCREDIT",
  "Status": "AUTHORISED",
  "Contact": { 
    "ContactID": "eaa28f49-6028-4b6e-bb12-d8f6278073fc" 
  },
  "Date": "2009-03-29",
  "LineAmountTypes": "Exclusive",
  "LineItems": [
    {
      "Description": "MacBook - White",
      "Quantity": 1.0000,
      "UnitAmount": 1995.00,
      "AccountCode": "720"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I've created the below Apex class

**Apex Class**

```
public class XeroCreditNote {

    public String Type;
    public String Status;
    public XeroContact Contact;
    public Date Date;  // <------- THIS LINE ERRORS
    public String LineAmountTypes;

    public LineItem[] LineItems;

    public class LineItem {

        public String Description;
        public Integer Quantity;
        public Decimal UnitAmount;
        public String AccountCode;

    }
}
```

But the line `public Date Date;` give me an error:

> Identifier name is reserved: Date

The class is serialsied like this:

```
return (List<XeroCreditNote>) JSON.deserialize(jsonSerialized, List<XeroCreditNote>.class);
```

**QUESTION**

I would like to be able to set the Apex property name to something that isn't reserved but make sure the correct property name is used when the object is serialized.

How can I do this with Apex?

Comment: Can you also provide the code where you perform serialization into JSON?

Comment: A solved problem in Java - [@JsonProperty](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations) - but no such mechanism in Apex.

Comment: @KeithC do you know if there is a Salesforce Idea for an addition like this to the Apex language?

Comment: @Robs I don't; if there isn't you could create one. Trouble is that only a few development oriented ideas get implemented a year and there are plenty of other development gaps already listed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use reserved keywords as keys in your JSON payload, the simplest solution is to just use `Map<String, Object>` rather than a concrete type.

```
system.debug(JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object>{
    'Date' => Date.today()
}));
```

The only other alternative I know of is string replacement, which I would be leery of implementing, but should also be viable. I would be careful to search for `"myKey":` rather than just `myKey` when you do any such replacement.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach for JSON output is the very hacky:

```
public class XeroCreditNote {
    ...
    public Date myVeryUniquePrefixDate;
    ..
}
```

and a replace of `myVeryUniquePrefix` with nothing in the JSON string.

Comment: That was going to be the second approach I recommended, but you already posted it so I'll omit. That said I think it's not the simplest. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson With the concrete classes already present it would be...

Comment: It's debatable either way. The OP has all options laid out in front of them now and can choose for themselves.

Comment: @AdrianLarson so the correct answer is both your approach and Keith C's approach, but I cannot mark both as correct. What should be done in this situation? If I create an answer from both your answers, it feels disingenuous, and most likely frowned upon, or is that OK?

Comment: @Robs  Adrian is a moderator here so I'd go with his opinion. But can't resist adding my 2c... If they have both provided useful information certainly upvote both. If you applied one or other to solve your problem accept that one. If its a tie just pick whichever you like and add a comment to that effect. All the answers are kept for reference so people can see both answers.

Comment: @KeithC historically, I've taken the approach you mentioned, but felt it was more of a hack than a proper solution...

Comment: @Robs I agree it’s a hack and personally favour the map approach too. So I’ve no problem with you accepting Adrian’s answer.